# Swift 3 - Swipe left to change label by using Array

Tags: swift3, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I beginner learning `Swift 3` - UISwipe gesture but cannot work if using Array.

This my code.

How can I code so the Label only change from "hello1" to "hello2" then swipe left again to "hello3". Also reverse swipe to right back from "hello3" to "hello2" and "hello1". or loop back to first one.

Thanks.

```
class ChangeLabelViewController: UIViewController {

var helloArray = ["Hello1", "Hello2", "Hello3"]
var currentArrayIndex = 0


@IBOutlet weak var helloLabel: UILabel!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ChangeLabelViewController.handleSwipes(sender:)))

    let rightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ChangeLabelViewController.handleSwipes(sender:)))

    leftSwipe.direction = .left
    rightSwipe.direction = .right

    view.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe)
    view.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipe)

    helloLabel.text = helloArray[currentArrayIndex]
}

func handleSwipes(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {

    if sender.direction == .left {
        helloLabel.text = helloArray[currentArrayIndex + 1]


    }

    if sender.direction == .right {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if sender.direction == .left {
    currentArrayIndex = (currentArrayIndex + 1) % 3
    helloLabel.text = helloArray[currentArrayIndex]
}

if sender.direction == .right {
    currentArrayIndex = (currentArrayIndex + 3 - 1) % 3 //if uInt
    helloLabel.text = helloArray[currentArrayIndex]
}
```

Comment: Thanks simalone. This is great tips and tutorials i have learn. I will digest the code further.

Comment: Hope this can help you! :) @JimmyWong

Answer (score 0):

you can also do it with below code,

```
func handleSwipes(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {

    if sender.direction == .left {

        if(currentArrayIndex < helloArray.count - 1)
        {
            currentArrayIndex += 1
            let indexPath = IndexPath(item: currentArrayIndex, section: 0)
            helloLabel.text = helloArray[indexPath.row]
        }
    }

    if sender.direction == .right {

        if(currentArrayIndex > 0)
        {
            currentArrayIndex -= 1
            if currentArrayIndex == -1
            {
                currentArrayIndex = 0
                let indexPath = IndexPath(item: currentArrayIndex, section: 0)
                helloLabel.text = helloArray[indexPath.row]
            }
            else {
                let indexPath = IndexPath(item: currentArrayIndex, section: 0)
                helloLabel.text = helloArray[indexPath.row]
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: I follow the code, when run until last array, the app crashed because "index out of range". Thanks for the guide.

Comment: Ohk.. now you can check

Comment: Thanks Jigar. The code worked perfect. I will try to understand it.

Comment: Its my pleasure Jimmy